# Clear explanation of Dialog implementation on bot framework V4

Tags: botframework

Is there someone who can explain how to code dialog from bot framework properly?
I'm trying to code from scratch using the empty bot template to understand every pieces of code and why and how they piece together. But even after reading so many times I don't how it is properly implemented or coding for dialogs in Microsoft Bot Framework. I've read the documentation from microsoft many times and many version or doc from microsoft but still can't comprehend how it link together every piece of code. Even blogs or website i found did not explain why such pieces of code is needed but just ask you to add this and that. I understand concept but not the mechanics. The code seems to span from startup.cs, yourMainBotLogic.cs, dialogClassName.cs, BotAccessors.cs which confuse me which are the steps the program is run on and how.

Please explain in detail why the pieces of code/components is needed/what use it has and why it has to be there in such files (e.g. Startup.cs). For example;

`var accessors = new BotAccessors(conversationState) { ConversationDialogState = conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), }; return accessors;`

Create a accessor for the DialogState and then return it. This is just example and my description of the code might not be right.

Answer (score 2):

Your question about how everything fits together is a bit broad, but I will attempt some explanation:

**`startup.cs`**: bot configuration should be loaded here, and singletons created.   Including `IStatePropertyAccessors`. Many of the samples contain a [BotConfig](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/search?l=C%23&q=botconfig) file with bot specific setup code, and call it from startup. Many samples also contain a bot file.  Bot files can make loading some bot services easier. But, they aren't necessary.  Ids and passwords can still be retrieved from App Settings, or web.config and your code can create the services.

Some things usually initialized in startup are:

- `ICredentialProvider` is used by the sdk to create the [BotAdapter](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs#L50) and provide [JWT Token Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication).  For single appid/password bots, the SDK provides a `SimpleCredentialProvider`. If your bot is using the integration libraries, you can create one during the `IBot` initialization, or just supply the botConfig with appid/pass:

webapi:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
         config.MapBotFramework(botConfig =>
        {
          var appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[MicrosoftAppCredentials.MicrosoftAppIdKey];
          var pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[MicrosoftAppCredentials.MicrosoftAppPasswordKey];

          botConfig.UseMicrosoftApplicationIdentity(appId, pass);
        }
    }
```

netcore:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddBot(options =>
     {
        options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(appId, appPassword);
     });           
    }
```

---

- [IStorage](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/IStorage.cs) is an implementation for interacting with a state store.  The sdk provides [MemoryStorage](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/MemoryStorage.cs)  [CosmosDbStorage](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/CosmosDbStorage.cs) and [AzureBlobStorage](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/AzureBlobStorage.cs)  These are each just using JsonSerializer to store and retrieve objects from the underlying storage.

---

- `BotState` are objects that provide keys into the IStorage implementation.  The SDK provides three examples:

  - [ConversationState](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConversationState.cs#L31) scoped by {channelId}/conversations/{conversationId}
  - [UserState](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/UserState.cs) scoped by {channelId}/users/{userId}
  - [PrivateConversationState](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/PrivateConversationState.cs) scoped by {channelId}/conversations/{conversationId}/users/{userId}

---

- `IStatePropertyAccessors` These are an implementation layer providing for typed access into the scoped BotState explained above.  When a get/set is performed, the actual state store is queried and persisted (through an internal cache provided by the sdk).

---

- `BotAccessors.cs` is just a container to hold the state classes and IStatePropertyAccessors.  This isn't needed, but is for convenience.

**`yourMainBotLogic.cs`**: this is where the adapter's OnTurn implementation exists, and should load the dialog stack and process the user's message. The dialog stack is managed by a dialog set that contains an IStatePropertyAccessor of DialogData type. When a get is performed on this property accessor by calling create context, the state store is queried to fill the dialog stack of the DialogContext.

**`dialogClassName.cs`** is a dialog implementation. The specific dialog types are delineated here: [Dialog types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#dialog-types) Examples of how to use them are in the samples on github and documentation.

As with other asp.net applications, startup is run when the application first loads (see [aspnet-web-api-poster](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) or [lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) and note that the [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core/) uses an IApplicationBuilder extension to add the message handler to the request pipeline [ApplicationBuilderExtensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/integration/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core/ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L68) and [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.WebApi/) uses an [HttpMessageHandler](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/integration/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.WebApi/BotMessageHandlerBase.cs) implementation). However, you can choose to not use the integration libraries, and create your own controllers. Like this sample: [MVC-Bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/30.asp-mvc-bot)

V4 additional references

- [Implement sequential conversation flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow)
- [Create advanced conversation flow using branches and loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow)
- [Gather user input using a dialog prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-prompts)
- [Managing state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state)
- [Save user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?tabs=csharp)
- [Implement custom storage for your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-custom-storage)

Comment: Thanks for your info. Can you go into more details about the pieces of code needed to get the structure of dialog up and its purpose? Making it as bare as possible, i'll give some try to see if i get it correctly //capture conversationstate `var conversationState = options.State.OfType<ConversationState>().FirstOrDefault(); ` //instantiate and return a dialogstate `var accessors = new BotAccessors(conversationState) { ConversationDialogState = conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), };` `return accessors;`.

Comment: As for BotAccessors class, we mainly store 2 property/reference which is the Accessor for DialogState and the ConversationState right?

Comment: As for MainBotLogic.cs which inherits IBot, but how does it makes it the main file? I don't see code pointing to this file. How will it get instantiated? The constructor can be parameterless to multi parameter such as `public EPBotBot(BotAccessors accessors)`. It seems like it is being called/instantiated everytime there is an activity. So it means getting reference of the DialogState created from startup everytime. `_dialogs = new DialogSet(accessors.ConversationDialogState);` `var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[] { };` `_dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("details", waterfallSteps));`

Comment: And adding new waterfallstep into the dialog stack each round? this makes it calling `_dialogs.Add(new WaterfallDialog("details", waterfallSteps));` and adding same dialogs on every activity. Will it check for duplication or I need to be doing it on my constructor? But won't this implementation be inefficient?

Comment: After that we need these code
`var dialogContext = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);`
`var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);`
to create the dialogContext and run it everytime a message activity is detected.
Is this all the components need for dialogs in its simplest form?

Comment: These should be separate questions.  This has gotten too large ... too much for one stack overflow question.